# Change Border Color of Div Based on Selection With CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a JavaScript function that allows us to change the border color of a div based on our selection. If the user selects Div 1 and Gray 1, the border-color of Div 1 will change to `color:#333333;` after hitting `Make Change`.

HTML:

```
<div id="div_6">
Div Selector:
<!-- Place Div Select Here -->
<select>
<option>Div 1</option>
<option>Div 2</option>
<option>Div 3</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
Color Selector:
<!-- Place Color Select Here -->
<select>
<option>Gray 1</option>
<option>Gray 2</option>
<option>Gray 3</option>
</select>
<!-- Place "Change Color" Button Here -->
<button>Change Color</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    /*color selectors*/
    #Gray1 {
    color:#333333;
    }
    #Gray2 {
    color:#777777;
    }
    #Gray3 {
    color:#CCCCCC;
    }
```

So the function will need to access these ID's. Please see the entire code / website here:

http://blog.drawyourpets.com/

I'm lost as to where to even start when creating this function. Do I need to assign to options various classes in the HTML? Thank you!

**EDIT** Of course the script will go in the `<script>` section of the `<head>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="This is a simple CSS, HTML, and JS Test"/>
<title>WebToMed Website Developer Test</title>
<style>
/* Add all CSS enteries here */
    #div_1 {
    background: red;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    }
    #div_2 {
    background: green;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    }
    #div_3 {
    background: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    width: 350px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    height: 50px;
    }
    #div_4 {
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;

    height: 300px;
    }
    #div_5 {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    }
    #div_6 {
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    padding: 20px;         
    }
    .container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    }
    /*color selectors*/
    #Gray1 {
    color:#333333;
    }
    #Gray2 {
    color:#777777;
    }
    #Gray3 {
    color:#CCCCCC;
    }
   </style>
<script>
/* Add any JavaScript here */
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yt2u8z3w/ Heres a working fiddle for you ;)

Comment: @mr.void Why didn't you paste that as an answer?

Comment: My english is to bad to explain the solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Assign values to your `options`, assign IDs to your `selects` in your HTML:

```
<div id="div_6">
Div Selector:
<!-- Place Div Select Here -->
<select id="div">
<option value="div1">Div 1</option>
<option value="div2">Div 2</option>
<option value="div3">Div 3</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
Color Selector:
<!-- Place Color Select Here -->
<select id="colors">
<option value="gray1">Gray 1</option>
<option value="gray2">Gray 2</option>
<option value="gray3">Gray 3</option>
</select>
```

2.) Create your JavaScript function within your `<script>` `</script>` tags. Declare your variables:

```
<script>
/* Add any JavaScript here */

function changecolor(){
/*gets selected value within select with ID "div"*/
var selectedvalue = document.getElementById("div").value;
/*gets selected value within select with ID "colors"*/
var selectedcolor = document.getElementById("colors").value;
```

3.) Create `If`, `Else If` statements to declare border styles based on selection:

```
if(selectedvalue == "div1" &&  selectedcolor == "gray1"){
      document.getElementById("div_1").style.borderColor="#333333";
      document.getElementById("div_1").style.borderWidth ="3px";
      document.getElementById("div_1").style.borderStyle ="solid";
}
else if(selectedvalue == "div2" &&  selectedcolor == "gray1"){
      document.getElementById("div_2").style.borderColor="#333333";
      document.getElementById("div_2").style.borderWidth ="3px";
      document.getElementById("div_2").style.borderStyle ="solid";
}
else if(selectedvalue == "div3" &&  selectedcolor == "gray1"){
      document.getElementById("div_3").style.borderColor="#333333";
      document.getElementById("div_3").style.borderWidth ="3px";
      document.getElementById("div_3").style.borderStyle ="solid";
}
else if(selectedvalue == "div1" &&  selectedcolor == "gray2"){
      document.getElementById("div_1").style.borderColor="#777777";
      document.getElementById("div_1").style.borderWidth ="3px";
      document.getElementById("div_1").style.borderStyle ="solid";
}
else if(selectedvalue == "div2" &&  selectedcolor == "gray2"){
      document.getElementById("div_2").style.borderColor="#777777";
      document.getElementById("div_2").style.borderWidth ="3px";
      document.getElementById("div_2").style.borderStyle ="solid";
}
else if(selectedvalue == "div3" &&  selectedcolor == "gray2"){
      document.getElementById("div_3").style.borderColor="#777777";
      document.getElementById("div_3").style.borderWidth ="3px";
      document.getElementById("div_3").style.borderStyle ="solid";
}
else if(selectedvalue == "div1" &&  selectedcolor == "gray3"){
      document.getElementById("div_1").style.borderColor="#CCCCCC";
      document.getElementById("div_1").style.borderWidth ="3px";
      document.getElementById("div_1").style.borderStyle ="solid";
}
else if(selectedvalue == "div2" &&  selectedcolor == "gray3"){
      document.getElementById("div_2").style.borderColor="#CCCCCC";
      document.getElementById("div_2").style.borderWidth ="3px";
      document.getElementById("div_2").style.borderStyle ="solid";
}
else if(selectedvalue == "div3" &&  selectedcolor == "gray3"){
      document.getElementById("div_3").style.borderColor="#CCCCCC";
      document.getElementById("div_3").style.borderWidth ="3px";
      document.getElementById("div_3").style.borderStyle ="solid";
}
};

</script>
```

There's no need to declare the styles for your ID's with CSS. You can remove the lines after `/*color selectors*/` within your `<style>` `</style>` tags. We are doing "inline styles" with JavaScript when we do this: `.style.borderColor="#333333";`. JavaScript styles, by the way, are usually similar to CSS styles but appear in camelCase. So `font-weight` in CSS = `fontWeight` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function change() {  
  $('#' + $('#select-div').val()).css('border', '3px solid ' + $('#select-color').val());
}
```

```css
#div_1 {
  background: red;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

#div_2 {
  background: green;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
}

#div_3 {
  background: blue;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  width: 350px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  height: 50px;
}

#div_4 {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
}

#div_5 {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#div_6 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}


/*color selectors*/

#Gray1 {
  color: #333333;
}

#Gray2 {
  color: #777777;
}

#Gray3 {
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.output {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.output > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_6">
  Div Selector:
  <select id="select-div">
    <option value="div1">Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Div 2</option>
    <option value="div3">Div 3</option>
  </select>
  <br /><br /> Color Selector:
  <select id="select-color">
    <option value="#777">Gray #555</option>
    <option value="#999">Gray #999</option>
    <option value="#AAA">Gray #BBB</option>
  </select>
  <button onClick="change();">Change Color</button>
  
  <div class="output">
    <div id="div1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2</div>
    <div id="div3">div 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hahaha, oh yes it is! :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay i will try to explain.

First you should define a function thats acts as Eventhandler for an event. There are multiple events that are fired by DOM-Elements like button, divs, etc.

For your case we want to listen for the click event of the button. (If a user clicks on the button, a method get executed)

If you work with jQuery this can easly done:

```
$('.submit').on('click', () => {

})
```

Notice: ive added a "submit"-Class to your Markup:

```
<button class="submit">Change Color</button>
```

On the next step we want the Values that the user selected via the selection. With jQuery this can done like so:

```
var idOfDiv = $('.divSelect option:selected').val();
var selectedGrayClass = $('.colorSelect option:selected').val();
```

Notice: ive added a "divSelect" and "colorSelect"-Classes to your Markup:

```
<select class="divSelect">
<option value="div1">Div 1</option>
<option value="div2">Div 2</option>
<option value="div3">Div 3</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
Color Selector:
<!-- Place Color Select Here -->
<select class="colorSelect">
<option value="gray1">Gray 1</option>
<option value="gray2">Gray 2</option>
<option value="gray3">Gray 3</option>
</select>
```

Notice: the values defined on the colorSelect selection should reference to some css classes:

```
.gray1 {border:1px solid gray}
.gray2 {border:1px solid #222}
.gray3 {border:1px solid #ccc}
```

On the final step we apply the data we've read from our selections:

```
$('#'+idOfDiv).removeClass().addClass(selectedGrayClass);
```

Notice: removeClass is there to remove a Class that may added before.

Complete solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/yt2u8z3w/

Comment: Please check my updated site - I've added your changes but still not getting the desired result: http://blog.drawyourpets.com/

Comment: you need to wrap the code in the document.ready function like in my fiddle example. document.ready is called if your browser has fully rendered the DOM, at this point you can modify DOM with jQuery

Comment: Please check my site again - the code is wrapped like in your fiddle example.

Comment: div1 not reference to any of your id's, you have div_1

Answer (score 1):

selected element,

```
document.querySelector('my_element_tag').onclick = function(){
   document.querySelector('my_element_tag_for_change_color').style.border = "1px solid #333";
};
```

Or if you have many element

```
 document.querySelectorAll('my_element_tag').forEach(function(element){
       element.onclick = function(){ 
           element.style.border = "1px solid #333";
      };
    });
```